# How does Ruby's $LOAD_PATH get affected in other files when changed in one file?

Tags: ruby

I have the following project directory structure:

```
.
├── bin
├── lib
│   ├── foo
│   │   ├── bar.rb
│   │   └── baz.rb
│   └── foo.rb
└── test
```

**foo.rb**:

```
require 'foo/bar'
```

**bar.rb**:

```
require 'foo/baz'
```

**baz.rb**:

```
puts "baz"
```

When I run `foo.rb` by adding the lib directory to the load path, Ruby prints out:

```
"baz"
```

I added the lib directory to the load path in `foo.rb`. How does it get added to load path in `foo/bar.rb` as well?

Comment: Um, because `$LOAD_PATH` is a *global* variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as other pointed out already LOAD_PATH is global.
You should not be relying on tricks like this though. In your case the right thing to do is to use **require_relative**

Answer (score 0):

`$LOAD_PATH` is a global variable shared between all files in a single ruby process. So when one file modifies it, any code executed after the modification will also use the modified version.

You can read more about global variables [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/doc/globals_rdoc.html)